# Boto3 Client Creation is Slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am running boto3 on AWS Lambda but getting a boto3 client is very slow. I am currently running a python3.9 runtime on AWS Lambda that creates handfuls of presigned url for s3 resources.

A key line of code required to generate the url with boto3 is

```
print("Getting boto3")
self.s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
print("Got client s3")
```

shockingly, the above single line of code takes a full 2000ms to execute according to the logs in cloudwatch:

```
2023-04-18T13:34:18.891-04:00   Getting boto3
2023-04-18T13:34:20.733-04:00   Got client s3
```

Is this normal and can I make it go faster? I saw an old post indicating that client acquisition speed might be improved by explicitly passing credentials or increasing memory size. It seems strange that the basic s3 interface cannot be acquired in less than 2s.

Comment: Make sure that the client initialization is outside of the lambda handler, this way it will be cached for (close) subsequent executions. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html

Comment: Lambda memory allotment also controls CPU allotment. IIRC, 128 MB means 1/24th of a CPU. You can see a comparison of times versus memory in an [answer I wrote several years ago, but which remains accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160907/42126) (and is for Java, but the same issue applies to Python -- there's a lot that happens when creating a client).

Comment: Initializing it outside the function handler makes it reusable for warm starts but more importantly it's [executed](https://hichaelmart.medium.com/shave-99-93-off-your-lambda-bill-with-this-one-weird-trick-33c0acebb2ea) with burst CPU and costs less (potentially nothing).

Comment: @jarmod - Nice! TIL

Comment: All this is good information. Simply increasing Memory did force boto3 s3 initialization to a handful of milliseconds.