# AmazonS3ClientBuilder Internal Server Error on Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have a LambdaFunction on Java 17 and I get a Internal Server Error, if i try to add the s3Client code snippet into my codebase. I really don't know how to get rid of it.

Because of IAM I don't have any credentials saved into my codebase.
I use: `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole`.

```
try {
     AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();

     apiResponse = new ApiResponse("success", 200);

} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
     apiResponse = new ApiResponse(e.getErrorMessage(), 500);
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SdkClientException e) {
     apiResponse = new ApiResponse(e.getLocalizedMessage(), 500);
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Let's imagine I remove `AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();`, then I will get statuscode 200. At the moment I don't even get a 500 status code, it's a "502 Bad Gateway" body: "Internal Server Error" in Postman.

Im using following packages:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.552</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.552</version>
</dependency>
```

Here are my CloudWatch Logs (Replaced all IDs with LONG_UUID):

```
INIT_START Runtime Version: java:17.v11 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1::runtime:LONG_UUID

START RequestId: LONG_UUID Version: $LATEST

2023-09-17T19:58:45.702Z LONG_UUID Task timed out after 3.07 seconds

END RequestId: LONG_UUID

REPORT RequestId: LONG_UUID Duration: 3067.36 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 91 MB  Init Duration: 398.87 ms    

INIT_START Runtime Version: java:17.v11 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1::runtime:LONG_UUID
```

I hope someone is able to help me, because I sit on this problem for 8 hours. I'm quite new to Java.

Comment: Did you try to increase the Lambda function timeout?

Comment: Yes, I did but didn't help

Comment: Try increasing the Lambda function's RAM.

Comment: Is the Lambda function deployed to a VPC? If so, and you haven't configured the VPC networking correctly, it could be timing out trying to connect to the AWS API.

Comment: Assuming that you have connectivity, as MarkB asked, a 128 MB memory allotment is far too little for a Java Lambda (because memory also controls CPU). You will need to increase your memory allotment to 1 GB or more (2 GB recommended), and should increase your timeout to 30 seconds or more (based on what the Lambda is doing). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65157346/how-to-improve-performance-of-initial-calls-to-aws-services-from-an-aws-lambda/65160907#65160907 for more information.